# trigger mysql on orders table where orders_id same with update process

Tags: mysql

i want update status on tabel orders  = 1 when status on table orders_foods = 1 where order_id= order_id same with update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER UPDATE ON orders_foods
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (new.status= '1' where old.order_id=new.order_id) THEN
     update  orders 
     set status= '1'
     where old.order_id=old.order_id
   END IF;
END;
```

orders table[image: orders table]
orders_foods table[image: orders_foods table]

i dont know how to write that order_id value in update proces to trigger and make that match to id on orders table

my problem is solved

```
BEGIN
    declare od_status_1 int default 0;
    declare od_number int default 0;
    select count(*) into od_number from orders_foods where orders_foods.order_id = new.order_id;
    select count(*) into od_status_1 from orders_foods where orders_foods.order_id = new.order_id and orders_foods.status = 1;

 if od_number = od_status_1 then
   update  orders
  set status= '1'
  where id=old.order_id;
 end if;
```

END

thx to P.Salmon

Comment: what problem your facing now?

Comment: i dont know how to write that order_id value in update proces to trigger and make that match to id on orders table

Comment: What should happen if only 1 part of an order is updated in orders_foods?

Comment: if only 1 part update statuse = 1 no update in orders table. that triger only run if all status = 1 where orders_foods.orders_id = orders.id

Comment: Your logic needs rethinking to take into account your last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order status should not change until all the order_detail status have changed to 1 then maybe something like this

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER UPDATE ON od
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        declare od_number int default 0;
        declare od_status_1 int default 0;
        select count(*) into od_number from od where od.order_id = new.order_id;
        select count(*) into od_status_1 from od where od.order_id = new.order_id and od.status = 1;
    insert into debug_table(msg) values
        (concat('new status:', new.status,' od found:',od_number,' od_status_1:',od_status_1))          ;

   IF new.status= 1  THEN
    insert into debug_table (msg) values
        (concat('in status check new status:', new.status,' od found:',od_number,' od_status_1:',od_status_1)   );
     if od_number = od_status_1 then
       update  o
      set status= '1'
      where id=old.order_id;
     end if;
   END IF;
END $$

delimiter ;
```

Note the use of a debug table to err debug.

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> /*
   /*> drop table if exists o,od;
   /*>
   /*> create table o(id int,status int);
   /*> create table od(id int,order_id int,status int);
   /*> */
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table o;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table od;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into o values
    -> (1,0),(2,0);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into od values
    -> (1,1,0),(2,1,0),(3,1,0),(4,2,0);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table debug_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> update od set od.status = 1 where od.id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from o join od on od.order_id = o.id;
+------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| id   | status | id   | order_id | status |
+------+--------+------+----------+--------+
|    1 |      0 |    1 |        1 |      1 |
|    1 |      0 |    2 |        1 |      0 |
|    1 |      0 |    3 |        1 |      0 |
|    2 |      0 |    4 |        2 |      0 |
+------+--------+------+----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> update od set od.status = 1 where od.id in (2,4);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from o join od on od.order_id = o.id;
+------+--------+------+----------+--------+
| id   | status | id   | order_id | status |
+------+--------+------+----------+--------+
|    1 |      0 |    1 |        1 |      1 |
|    1 |      0 |    2 |        1 |      1 |
|    1 |      0 |    3 |        1 |      0 |
|    2 |      1 |    4 |        2 |      1 |
+------+--------+------+----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from debug_table;
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+------+
| id | msg                                                   | MSG2 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+------+
|  1 | new status:1 od found:3 od_status_1:1                 | NULL |
|  2 | in status check new status:1 od found:3 od_status_1:1 | NULL |
|  3 | new status:1 od found:3 od_status_1:2                 | NULL |
|  4 | in status check new status:1 od found:3 od_status_1:2 | NULL |
|  5 | new status:1 od found:1 od_status_1:1                 | NULL |
|  6 | in status check new status:1 od found:1 od_status_1:1 | NULL |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

MariaDB [sandbox]>

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER UPDATE ON orders_foods
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        declare od_number int default 0 got eror #1064

Comment: #1146 - Table 'tugasakhir.debug_table' doesn't exist

Comment: ok thx i got that bro this BEGIN
  declare od_status_1 int default 0;
        declare od_number int default 0;
        select count(*) into od_number from orders_foods where orders_foods.order_id = new.order_id;
        select count(*) into od_status_1 from orders_foods where orders_foods.order_id = new.order_id and orders_foods.status = 1;

     if od_number = od_status_1 then
       update  orders
      set status= '1'
      where id=old.order_id;
     end if;
END

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Delimiter //  
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER UPDATE ON orders_foods
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       IF (new.status= 1 and old.order_id=new.order_id) THEN
         update  orders 
         set status= 1
         where id=old.order_id;
       END IF;
    END;
//
Delimiter ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 8

Comment: ; missing in update statement. now corrected. check now

Comment: i try that before and got same #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: i dont have db here so couldn't check. sorry

Comment: CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `adress` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ;
CREATE TABLE `orders_foods` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `food_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
);

Comment: @gaj you might want to set delimiters

Comment: @P.Salmon ha :) got.. 
riskiwahyu hope now you can solve. I have corrected in my answer

Comment: that trigger run. but that change status in orders=1 when only 1 orders_food status change.

Comment: can i give check first on that triger like select status on orders_food with same order_id if status all select = 1 then trigger updt status on orders to 1?

Comment: no select statement.. 
already checking new.status= 1 (this is order_food status only). if you say status changed from some other value to 1 then only order table should updated then then change the if condition to like "IF (new.status= 1 and new.status <> old.status and old.order_id=new.order_id) THEN"

Comment: maybe like this BEGIN
       IF (new.status= 1 and new.status=old.status and new.order_id=order_id) THEN
         update  orders 
         set status= 1
         where id=old.order_id;
       END IF;
    END

Comment: but i got  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TUGASAKHIR\admin\Models\Admin.php:246

Comment: if status = 1 where new.order_id=order_id <all the same order_id then change status in order = 1